# Creating a wordpress plugin - plugin not finding CSS files

Tags: php, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm creating a wordpress plugin and getting 404 not found on css files.
Heres the code (it's in the main php file for the plugin)

```
function callback_for_setting_up_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', ver:null);
    wp_enqueue_style('main-sincoe-style', __DIR__.'/css/main.css', ver:null);
    echo  readfile(__DIR__.'/css/main.css');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'callback_for_setting_up_scripts');
```

So two things:

- **1st** echo works as it should - it reads out the whole css file - so it shouldn't be a path problem as far as I know.
- **2nd** Bootstrap works as it should so there should not be a problem in the function

So i'm stuck a bit here - thanks for any help (I'm on Mac if that changes anything - just moved so maybe those are some write/read permissions that i have not put up yet)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're supposed to pass the URL to the file, not the (absolute) path to the file. See [wp_enqueue_style() Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/#parameters) and [User Contributed Notes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/#user-contributed-notes). Also, lose the `ver:` bit from your `enqueue` calls, I don't think that's a valid value.

Comment: See [plugin_dir_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_url/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Moshe Gross

plugin_dir_url() worked - the working code:

```
function callback_for_setting_up_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', ver:null);
    wp_enqueue_style('main-sincoe-style',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'/css/main.css', ver:null);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'callback_for_setting_up_scripts');
```